# Outlook system tray icon + gear

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

could you guys tell what this Outlook system tray icon means? (It's a casual Outlook icon & gear, I guess...?)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This means that Outlook is used by another program. You can find the program that uses Outlook by using Process Explorer, for example: just open process tree and find the outlook.exe child item.